# When is a NSManagedObject really accessible?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsobject, nsobjectcontroller

I have a problem.

I have an NSObjectController called "mapController" and I want to put some defaults when the object is created. I do this inside the **windowControllerDidLoadNib** method of my document, as suggested by the docs. But…

```
if (![mapController content]){   // No map defined yet.
    [mapController add: self];   // This should create the instance.

    NSLog(@"%@",[mapController content]); // Gives NULL.
```

I tried:

```
    BOOL ok = [mapController fetchWithRequest:nil merge:NO error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",[mapController content]); // Gives NULL.
```

The content of mapController is in the Core Data "scratch pad" but I can't access it. I have to set one of its attributes like this:

```
    [[mapController content] setValue:[matrix colorReference] forKey:@"mapData"];
```

This gives no error, the file is marked as changed, but it I test the value:

```
    NSLog(@"%@",[mapController content]); // Gives NULL.
```

When the heck it the controller's content really HERE? Something appears on the screen but… what actually? Reading the docs doesn't help me…

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the answer in the docs:

> **add:** Creates a new object and sets it as the receiver’s content object.
>
> Discussion
>
> Creates a new object of the appropriate entity (specified by
>   entityName) or class (specified by objectClass)—see newObject—and sets
>   it as the receiver’s content object using addObject:.
>
> Special Considerations
>
> Beginning with Mac OS X v10.4 **the result of this method is deferred
>   until the next iteration** of the runloop so that the error presentation
>   mechanism can provide feedback as a sheet.

That's why

```
[[mapController content] setValue:[matrix colorReference] forKey:@"mapData"];
```

worked fine when called elsewhere in the app. It was a few iterations later…

Well… maybe this post will save you a couple of hours you could use to sleep longer.

Regards,

Bernard

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its your mapController, I think it is your NSLog.  Try this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", mapController);
```

also try getting simple data from the content, like the float value of the CGColorRef so you can use other formatters like %f.

I would have tested this but I cannot seem to create an instance of NSObjectController because it is an undeclared identifier.  What framework is it defined in?  Did you have to #import anything?